# "& nbsp " editor wordpress

Tags: wordpress, editor

In the editor of wordpress, the visual tab , when I press the enter key to generate a line break between lines or paragraphs or phrases , wordpress instead of making the newline writes me "& nbsp " and does not generate the jump line .

Why does this happen?

As you fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the WYSIWYG editor code. Have you tried updating Wordpress core?

Comment: I'm using version 4.0 wordpress

Comment: You're definitely going to want to update wordpress core anyway, even if it doesn't fix this problem. Your website is vulnerable to security risks if if's not updated.

Once you update, you will be able to tell if it's a problem with the core code or possibly a contributed plugin.

Comment: I think i found the problem. In my functions.php there is two lines: remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' ); , i think that is the problem

Comment: As long as that works for you. But still - update your core...